# What happens when I use the .dissolve function in GeoPandas on polygons that do not border with each other?

Tags: python, pandas, polygon, geopandas

Imagine I want to obtain a single layer from the union of three polygons that do not border with each other, i.e. they do not have any edge in common. What would be the right command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `dissolve` creates MultiPolygons if those to be dissolved are not adjacent.